# Using Java.util.scanner with GWT

Tags: gwt, java.util.scanner

for some reason when I try to use scanner with gwt, i get the following error:

```
No source code is available for type java.util.Scanner; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

I looked around and it seems the "No source code is available for type xxxx" errors are due to not having a Javascript equivalent type for the Java type.
Is scanner not able to be used with GWT?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
...
public void submit(){
    String text = editor.getEditor().getText();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(text);
    while(input.hasNextLine()){
        String line = input.nextLine();
        if(line.contains("//")){
            cInfo.setDone(false);
            cInfo.setCode(text);
            return;
        }
        cInfo.setDone(true);
        cInfo.setCode(text);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

java.util.Scanner is not part of the GWT JRE Emulation. If you need a detail overview of what is inside the emulation here is the link to the docs:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation#Package_java_util

Comment: Is there any sort of GWT alternative to scanner that you know of?

Comment: what are you trying to do, maybe we can suggest something better

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I ended up using regex and split to split the text into an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your code (at least the one in the current version of your question) is probably<sup>[*]</sup> equivalent to

```java
public void submit() {
  String text = editor.getEditor().getText();

  if ("".equals(text))
    return;

  cInfo.setDone(!text.contains("//"));
  cInfo.setCode(text);
}
```

However, I have a feeling that this may not actually be what want to do (or is it?)

If you need to split strings on the client side, I usually recommend the Splitter class in [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). Most of its methods are [GwtCompatible](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/annotations/GwtCompatible.html), and (together with CharMatcher, Joiner, ...) it's great to use both on the client and server side of your Java code.

<sub>[*] assuming, that setDone and setCode are simple setters without side effects</sub>